# moving as many lines of code # out of main as possible

Tags: ruby

how can i move lines of code out of main as possible?
without messing the program. Please ask me if you didn't understated the question. thank you

```
def main
  a_file = File.new("mydata.txt", "w") # open for writing
  if a_file  # if nil this test will be false
    write_data_to_file(a_file)
    a_file.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to write!"
  end

  a_file = File.new("mydata.txt", "r") # open for reading
  if a_file  # if nil this test will be false
    read_data_from_file(a_file)
    a_file.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to read!"
  end
end

main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can i move lines of code out of main as possible?
>   without messing the program.

That's easy:

```
def do_it
  a_file = File.new("mydata.txt", "w") # open for writing
  if a_file  # if nil this test will be false
    write_data_to_file(a_file)
    a_file.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to write!"
  end

  a_file = File.new("mydata.txt", "r") # open for reading
  if a_file  # if nil this test will be false
    read_data_from_file(a_file)
    a_file.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to read!"
  end
end

def main
  do_it
end

main
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows.

```
def main
  file_op("w", :write_data_to_file, "write")
  file_op("r", :read_data_from_file, "read")
end

def file_op(new_arg, file_op, msg) 
  a_file = File.new("mydata.txt", new_arg)
  send(file_op, a_file)
  a_file.close
end
```

Comment: `a_file` cannot be `falsey` here though.

Comment: @Aleksei, good point. I've done an edit. Exceptions could be raised (such as a disk-full error), which one may want to rescue, but I've not done that.

Answer (score 0):

```
### CONSTANTS ##
READING = 'reading'
WRITING = 'writing'
FILE_NAME = 'myFile.txt'

# Method for writing file 
def write_file
  a_file = open_file_for(WRITING)
  if a_file  # if nil this test will be false
   write_data_to_file(a_file)
    a_file.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to write!"
  end
end 

# Method to reading file
def read_file
  a_file = open_file_for(READING)
  if a_file  # if nil this test will be false
   read_data_from_file(a_file)
   a_file.close
  else
   puts "Unable to open file to read!"
  end
end 

# Method For opening File
def open_file_for(action)
  mode = 
    case action
    when READING
      "r"
    when WRITING
      "w"
    end 
  File.new(FILE_NAME, mode)
end 

# Main Calling Method
def main 
  write_file
  read_file
end
```

You can also improve this method with class mechanism, go ahead and try good luck.